# Inflate RelativeLayout inside LinerLayout in a loop gets OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi I'm trying to inflate a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout but I keep getting the OutOfMemoryError in my device. I am not quite sure if I'm supposed to inflate a view inside a loop bit I just don't know how else to achieve this. This code works just fine If I remove the loop and inflate the TextView just one time.

This is the layout i'm inflating:

activity_academic_status_period_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/academic_status_period_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/academic_status_grade"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/academic_status_grade_circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="20"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/academic_status_first_period"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/academic_status_grade"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Nth Period"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#000" >

</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

code where I call inflatePeriodGrade()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    instanceType = super.instance;
    instanceId = super.instanceId;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    inflatePeriodGrade();
}
```

This is the code in my activity:

```
public void inflatePeriodGrade() {
    AcademicStatusController.getInstance(this);

    ArrayList<PeriodInfo> periodsInfo = AcademicStatusController
            .getPeriodsInfo(instanceType, instanceId);
    Iterator<PeriodInfo> it = periodsInfo.iterator();

    // Find LinearLayout where the period grade will be placed
    LinearLayout llDisplayData = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.help_relative_layout_for_periods);

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        // Inflate the view of the period
        View customView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_academic_status_period_layout, null);

        // Remove all the items in the LinearLayout
        llDisplayData.removeAllViews();

        // Set the text to the TextView.
        TextView tvtxt = (TextView) customView
                .findViewById(R.id.academic_status_grade);
        tvtxt.setText(it.next().getName());

        llDisplayData.addView(customView);
    }
}
```

Thing is I need to inflate the layout for each element in the periods ArrayList (which has max 5 elements) but it doesn't work and I'm not really sure why. Also, how can I add the TextViews one right of the other so I could have something like this:

I'm just trying to inflate the layout that contains the little blue circle with the text into the RelativeLayout that contains the whole view.

**EDIT** 
StackTrace usging Log.d("myapp", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception())); in onCreate();

```
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878): java.lang.Exception
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at      com.akdemia.views.AcademicStatusActivity.onCreate(AcademicStatusActivity.java:36)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-23 10:27:55.711: D/myapp(23878):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**
This is the layout I'm trying to make look like the image below. I'm also using NavigationDrawer.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/carla123456"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/academic_status_banner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_team" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/academic_status_average"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/akdemia_blue"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Promedio: ND"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/academic_status_subjects"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/academic_status_banner"
        android:background="@color/akdemia_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Materias"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/academic_status_subjects_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/academic_status_subjects" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/help_relative_layout_for_periods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<!-- should not be larger than 320 to show content -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get stack trace in Logcat?

Comment: I don't. And I just tried to get the error again and the log keeps showing this repeatedly with different times of course.   09-22 17:53:49.071: D/dalvikvm(1268): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1829K, 44% free 9719K/17184K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 24ms
09-22 17:53:49.071: D/dalvikvm(1268): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms

Comment: Are you running on a device or emulator?

Comment: No, I'm runing it in my cellphone. I ran it again and I didn't get the error, just the message I posted above but multiple times

Comment: Does anything different happen if you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: For debugging log `periodsInfo.size` before the loop. You may also try to set `periodsInfo = null` at the very end (just out of desperation).

Comment: for looping through an ArrayList, it's best practice to use the modified for loop:

`for(PeriodInfo info : periodsInfo ){//code here}`

Comment: Please post the code that is calling inflatePeriodGrade.

Comment: changing the way of looping through the arrayList did change something! I don't get the error anymore, and the textViews inflate just fine, but now I need to set the textview one right to the other, any ideas? thank you @chjarder

Comment: Hi, @MichaelKrause just edited my question to add the code you asked me to post :)

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see where you set the content view in your onCreate.  That will be a problem.   Also, I'm wondering if you could also post the stack trace +- 100 or so log statements on either side?

Comment: Yes that is the result. I only see the last name in my periodsInfo array inflated. I'm not getting any exceptions and if I print the stack trace in the onCreate method I get what I just posted on my new edit.

Comment: Any idea of how many times that loops gets executed?

Comment: in this moment, three times

Comment: You want to have multiple inflated views inside your llDisplayData LinearLayout, no?  If so, comment out this line: llDisplayData.removeAllViews(); as it will remove any children previously added in your loop leaving you with just the last one added.

Comment: Just did that and seems to work but the TextViews are being located in the exact same position so I think they are overlapping each other. How can I put one textview next to the other?

Comment: What does the LinearLayout with id help_linear_layout_for_periods look like in your layout file?

Comment: Hi, @MichaelKrause just edited mi question to add the layout, I just realised it is actually a RelativeLayout and not a LinearLayout I already changed the name to avoid any confusions.

Comment: Sorry Carla, I should have been more specific: I need to see what the parent layout for this help_linear_layout_for_periods RelativeLayout looks like.  Is it a LinearLayout?  What orientation does it have?

Comment: Oh, my bad! Check my new edit, I added the whole xml file. :)